# What am I not understanding about the canonical proof that no finite field is algebraically closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Wikipedia gives what seems to be the canonical proof that no finite field is algebraically closed, under the article titled “Algebraically closed field”. It gives the following definition: “In abstract algebra, an algebraically closed field F contains a root for every non-constant polynomial in F[x], the ring of polynomials in the variable x with coefficients in F.” It then later states: “Also, no finite field F is algebraically closed, because if a1, a2, …,an are the elements of F, then the polynomial (x − a1)(x − a2) ••• (x − an) + 1 has no zero in F.” However, unless I’m grossly overlooking something, the cited polynomial is not non-constant, and therefore this proof is invalid. This same argument is repeated here on MSE:

[Show that for every prime $p$, the field $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is not algebraically closed.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541109/show-that-for-every-prime-p-the-field-mathbbz-p-is-not-algebraically-clo)

and elsewhere on the web. However, I spotted a different (at least, different-looking) argument on the web that may be valid:

http://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/4127/notes/VI-33.pdf
(Corollary 3.11, and the Note that follows it)

So, my question is: what gives with this result? Is it just me, or is its most widely cited proof invalid?

Comment: Your post would be easier to read if you used MathJax/LaTex formatting.  A homegrown [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) will get you started.  A [quick overview](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) may be helpful.

Comment: @hardmath: Thanks. I'll take a look at those links later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the distinction is between "the function $f$ is constant on its domain" (which is true for the polynomial written here, with domain the finite field -- the values is everywhere 1) and "a polynomial in which the coefficients of $x, x^2, \ldots$ are all zero", which one might reasonably call a "constant polynomial". I believe that the meaning intended in the proof is this latter one. And the cited polynomial has coefficient $1$ for the $x^n$ term, where $n$ is the number of elements of the field, hence is not a "constant polynomial".

Comment: You were able to understand that double negation "no non-cosntant". I wasn't . +1

Comment: Indeed there are only finitely many functions from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to itself, but infinitely many polynomials (of unbounded degree) with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.  So inevitably there will be different polynomials whose evaluations produce the same functions.